# Unity Object Always Instantiating at 0, 0, 0

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

I am trying to make simple terrain generation in my Minecraft clone. Whenever I try to run the script, it places ALL the instantiated objects at the position 0, 0, 0. Here is my C# code for terrain generation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TerrainGen : MonoBehaviour {

    public int radius;
    public int maxHeight;

    public GameObject block;

    void Start ()
    {
        for (float x = 0; x < radius; x+=1)
        {
            for (float z = 0; z < radius; z+=1)
            {
                float y = Random.Range(1, maxHeight);
                Vector3 v = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                GameObject newBlock = Instantiate(block, v, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                Debug.Log("Block's Position: " + newBlock.transform.position + " | Wanted Position: " + v);
            }
        }
    }

    void Update ()
    {

    }
```

Comment: You forgot the code.

Comment: The cliffhanger is killing me

Comment: Sorry, i accidentally posted it before pasting the code in

Comment: @bloobchube - Out of curiosity, try replacing `Vector3 v = new Vector3(x, y, z);` with  `Vector3 v = new Vector3(100, 100, y)`. What happens then?

Comment: Pikamander2 I did that. All of the blocks still remain at 0, 0, 0.

Comment: Works for me. Which Unity version are you using?

Comment: Try changing those to `public int radius = 20` and `public int maxHeight = 1`. Does that change anything?

Comment: Pikamander2  It does not change anything.

Comment: buxter I am using Version 5.0.0f4 Personal.

Comment: It's in the About window. If it's OSX, then Unity -> About Unity. If it's Win, then Help -> About Unity. As well, are you on osx or win?

Comment: buxter I'm on OSX 10.9.5.

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest you updating to the newest version 5.1.2p3, though I don't think it's connected. Which values do you set for radius  and   maxHeight

Comment: I set the values in the Unity editor window with a GameObject called TerrainGenerator.

Comment: I don't see problems with this script, it works for me. So it should be sth else. Any chance to get a look at the project?

Comment: From your comment below "I tried that. It logged that the wanted position and actual block position were both the same and that the block position was not at where it was in-game. "   Just in case, you are not using an empty gameobject as a block, right?

Comment: No. I am using a cube with a Block script attached to it.

Comment: Does the block script change any transformation values?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `radius` hasn't been set to a value yet, so your for loops are only running once.

Since `x` and `z` start at zero, and they're both only running once, the `x` and `z` position of the object are being set to zero.

Comment: Thanks, but no, that isn't the problem. In the Unity level editor window, I set the variable radius and max height to 20 and 1.

Comment: @bloobchube - use Debug.Log to check the values of z and x inside the loop. I think that they're zero, for one reason or another.

Comment: Pikamander2 I tried that. It logged that the wanted position and actual block position were both the same and that the block position was not at where it was in-game.

Comment: That sounds like a parenting problem to me. Does the block prefab have parents/children?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for all of the trouble I have been causing to all of you wonderful people. Of course, I was ignorant, and the problem was not with my terrain gen script, but with my block script!!!! I was constantly setting the position of the block and I was being very stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
GameObject newBlock = Instantiate(block, v, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
newBlock.transform.position = v;
```

I don't know if this will fix your problem, and I don't know either if it's a bug with the instantiate method or if it's a misunderstanding by us, but everytime I try to instantiate an UI element, I need to reset the position (and the scale) in the same way as above. Never tried with a cube, but with UI it does the job.